# How can I use a specific style on a font with 47 styles?

Tags: html, css

[image]I want to use SF Pro Expanded in the SF Pro font on the web. But I'm not sure how I would make it use the expanded style instead of just the normal SF Pro font (if that makes sense)

How would I do this in CSS?

```
@font-face {
  font-family: "SFPro-ExpandedLight";
  src: url(font/SF-Pro.ttf);
}

body {
  background-image: url("websitebg.png");
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-family: "SFPro-ExpandedLight", sans-serif;
}
```

This just uses the normal SF Pro font instead of Expanded

I tried changing the font weight to "expanded" but with no luck

Comment: Find the correct [descriptors to set on the `@font-face`](http://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@font-face)?

Comment: Please don't send a font with 47 styles to your users

Comment: @Zachiah well thats the thing, I don't really know how I can just extract that 1 style from the style pack. I've tried looking for software to do that but I've found nothing

Comment: Supposedly [fontforge](https://fontforge.org/en-US/) can do it. Haven't tried though

Comment: @Zachiah I just tried opening the font, it spat out a quadrillion errors all saying "Bad device table" before locking up and closing abruptly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `font-variation-settings` css property. Check out this codepen  by Chris Coyier https://codepen.io/chriscoyier/pen/RwMQYyQ

specifically lines 57 to 63 which have this block

```
tr:nth-child(4) {
  @for $i from 1 through 10 {
    td:nth-child(#{$i + 1}) {
      font-variation-settings: "wght" #{(($i - 1) * 110) + 5}, "wdth" 130;
    }
  }
}
```

Converting to CSS I believe light expanded would be

`font-variation-settings: "wght" 225, "wdth" 130;`

You can read more in [this article](https://chriscoyier.net/2022/08/02/%E2%80%A6)

It's worth nothing that `font-variation-settings` has pretty [conditional support](https://caniuse.com/?search=font-variation-settings) (requiring specific OS updates to support)

Comment: And here is the article for more reading: https://chriscoyier.net/2022/08/02/actually-the-san-francisco-typeface-does-ship-as-a-variable-font/

Comment: Please put the article in the answer if you think it is useful. Comments are meant to be temporary and deletable with no adverse effects

Comment: I added it as a comment while editing the post, just in case fullpwn saw the answer while I was editing, but noted

Comment: Solved! I got the weight to work, now just have to find a weight I like!